# Linux Driver for Drawing Tablet

Tags: drivers, graphics-tablet

I've got my eye on a fancy schmancy drawing monitor (draw on the screen). Here is a link to the exact product, [it's a Ugee 1910.](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA4JM1NR7374)

Unfortunately since its a fairly niche product it doesn't have a driver for linux and I just can't bring myself to add an OSX or god forbid windows system to my desk. Am I completely out of luck or is there some way to get the windows or mac driver working on a linux machine (I use ubuntu 14.04 at the moment)?

I've found a variety of solutions but they are all for the screenless graphics tablets. I can't find any confirmation online that anyone has gotten one of these monitors working in linux. Where do I even start? I don't know anything about porting drivers and if that is my only hope i'm open to going down that road, but I need some guidance as to where to even start.

**Update:** Turns out that there is another pen monitor that is supported in linux using the [Digimend Kernel Drivers](https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers). The only one I can actually find on their list of supported devices is the [Yiynova.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B010W69BMY) I don't particularily like the look of the monitor but apparently it works decent and people seem pretty happy with it. The product actually lists support for linux on the product page and although they don't have downloadable drivers, with a bit of digging you can find a recommendation to the digimend project on their website.

This update doesn't really answer my question, but at least there is a viable alternative.